# Python - Using pyodbc to connect to remote server using info from Excel data connection

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I have an excel (albeit, one that's on our company server) that has a data connection to our SQL database so we can make nice pivot tables.

I would like to get that data into python (on my local computer) so I can do some faster analysis.

I have installed pyodbc.

Here is the "connection string" from the excel:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=**mypassword**;Persist Security Info=True;User
ID=**myusername**;Initial Catalog=**catalogename**;Data 
Source=**datasourcename**;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto 
Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=**workstationid**;Use 
Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False
```

and now I have the python script:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(DRIVER='{SQL Server}',SERVER='***server ip address**',DATABASE='**cataloguename**',UID='**myusername**',PWD='**mypassword**')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

and I am getting errors saying that SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need the single quotes around each field, and may need a port... Try something like this:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.123.456;PORT=1433;DATABASE=yourdb;UID=your_user;PWD=your_pw;')
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi FlipperPA, thanks for the suggestion but I still can't connect.. I am getting the following error:
Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (2); [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')

Which is the same regardless of the credentials I am using. It suggests I am using the wrong details but I don't know which could be wrong?

Comment: Are you attempting to connect from pyodbc on the same machine that you're connecting from Excel on?

Comment: Yes, and I just realised that for server, not to use the IP address but COMPANYSQLSERVER and that did the trick!

Comment: Fantastic! I'm glad you got it worked out. If you could mark the answer as correct to help someone with the same connection string issue, that'd be great.

Comment: Awesome! This helped me so much!

Answer (score 2):

For connecting to the remote server SQL, I found this solution to work.
Here, the port number is [important](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15) which is **1433**.

```
import pyodbc
server = 'tcp:***your_server_name*,1433' (i.e your_server_name = abcd.mydomain.com)
database = 'your_DB_NAME' 
username = 'Your_USER_NAME' 
password = 'YOUR_PASSWORD' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()`enter code here`
cursor.execute('SELECT top 1 * FROM [DBNAME].[SchemaNAME].[YourTable]')
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

And If you don't have username and password then just remove username and password and add `Trusted_Connection=yes`

See here example:

```
import pyodbc
server = 'tcp:***your_server_name*,1433' (i.e your_server_name = abcd.mydomain.com)
database = 'your_DB_NAME' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';Trusted_Connection=yes')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT top 1 * FROM [DBNAME].[SchemaNAME].[YourTable]')
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

[Ckick here for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: what is the ```tcp:**``` right before the server for?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still active, but I'll leave this here anyway.

It's a good idea to double check that the IP of your SQL server is [public and not private](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). I spent a long time trying to use various ODBC connectors on my company's server only to discover that the IP was private so any cloud application couldn't connect to it.

As far as your python analysis goes, if it's a private IP, you need to verify that your computer is on the same server and the user you are signed in as has permission to access the database.

Answer (score -1):

Please install SQL server driver by going to control panel - administrative tools - ODBC connections

Comment: Include some steps of instalation, maybe some links.